# How can I know the absolute position of the text input cursor in a QTextEdit?

Tags: qt

QTextEdit apparently has a textCursor() method that returns a QTextCursor, but this is a Cursor to modify the document. I see no way to get the actual absolute (or relative to the widget) position of the blinking cursor in the GUI. How can I retrieve this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QTextEdit has a method called cursorRect() that returns the QRect containing the position information of the cursor.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#cursorRect-2

> **QRect QTextEdit::cursorRect ( const QTextCursor & cursor ) const** 
>   returns a rectangle (in viewport coordinates) that includes thecursor. 
>   **QRect QTextEdit::cursorRect () const** 
>   returns a rectangle (in viewport coordinates) that includes the cursor of the text edit.

QRect shall be able to provide the coordinates.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qrect.html

Comment: Uhm... strange that is a rect. Maybe it's because you can make it bigger? That's exactly what I needed though. Thanks